# type-safe builder example kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to have following person object in Kotlin :

```
       var p = person {
            age = 22
            gender = "male"
            name {
                first = "Ali"
                last = "Rezaei"
            }
        }
```

I have following code to build it :

```
data class Person(var age: Int? = null, var gender: String? = null
                      , var name : Name? = null) {
    }

    fun name(init: Name.() -> Unit): Name {
        val n = Name()
        n.init()
        return n
    }

    data class Name(var first: String? = null, var last : String? = null)

    fun person(init: Person.() -> Unit): Person {
        val p = Person()
        p.init()
        return p
    }
```

But when I print it, the result is following :

```
Person(age=22, gender="male", name=null)
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign to `name`.  This ended up working for me...

```
var p = person {
    age = 22
    gender = "male"
    name = name {
        first = "Ali"
        last = "Rezaei"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could make `name` an extension function on `Person` that assigns the `Name` to the `Person` instead of returning it:

```
fun Person.name(init: Name.() -> Unit) {
    val n = Name()
    n.init()
    this.name = n
}
```

You could even consider a more concise syntax for the same, like this:

```
fun Person.name(init: Name.() -> Unit) {
    this.name = Name().apply(init)
}
```

---

Shameless plug for my [repository](https://github.com/zsmb13/VillageDSL) discussing DSL design and containing examples.